# PC doesn't identify TV monitor after disconnecting the HDMI cable

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

Everything worked well. The PC identified the TV and I could get video and audio into it.

Yesterday I switched to a new desk and had to take out all the cables. When I returned the HDMI cable to its location, the PC failed to identify the TV.

Same drivers, same cables, same equipment. I don't get why a simple disconnection would make this happen. Any help?

Windows 7.

Comment: Try using a different cable.